# What companies would be great for entry level data science/ machine learning programmers to help fight for a good cause?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, career

I am just starting to learn about machine learning, and I have taken some intro classes in MATLAB and Python. I want to know about fulfilling careers and fields programmers can pursue to help me determine my career direction. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If I were you, I would ask which sectors instead of which companies. And I would answer either medicine or elderly care.

Comment: I think as you learn more ml, hopefully if you use google, you'll see more articles and stuff related to ML (magic of google) and those articles will give you a broad idea of the upcoming field of ml.....To;Dr as you progress thru ur Learning you'll get a feel of possibilities in ml

Comment: Thank you, and yes you are right, I do want to learn about sectors that make use of Machine Learning. I asked for companies, though, because ML is used in so many sectors (public health like you said, but mostly marketing and research from what I have seen) that I wanted to see more of examples of ML being used for a cause.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join companies for a good cause then my opinion would be look for startups. Startups have broader definition of work and more freedom with data. You can search through their goals and find what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try to use that in my searches:)